# i want to get key value of array in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a .rb file I am using `result = JSON.parse(res.body)['data']['results']` and get

```json
[
  {"suggestion":"Lineman","id":"49.10526"},
  {"suggestion":"Linguist","id":"27.10195"},
  {"suggestion":"Librarian","id":"25.47"},
  {"suggestion":"Lifeguard","id":"33.39"},
  {"suggestion":"Line Cook","id":"35.30125"},
  {"suggestion":"Life Coach","id":"21.209"},
  {"suggestion":"Life Guard","id":"33.1001"}
]
```

now I want an array like

```rb
[
  "Lineman",
  "Linguist",
  "Librarian",
  "Lifeguard",
  "Line Cook",
  "Life Coach",
  "Life Guard"
]
```

What should I apply to `JSON.parse(res.body)['data']['results']`?

Comment: `result` is merely an array. That it came from a JSON string is irrelevant to your question.

Comment: It is unlikely that the top code block is what you receive from JSON parse since JSON parsing is always converted to `String` keys and what you have shown will result in `Symbol` keys. *Yes, this distinction is important*

Answer (score 1):

You can use `Enumerable#map`:

```rb
  other_result = result.map { |val| val['suggestion'] }
```

it returns a new array with results of applying the block to initial array elements

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
suggestions = result.pluck(:suggestion)
# ["Lineman", "Linguist", "Librarian", "Lifeguard", "Line Cook", "Life Coach", "Life Guard"]
```

This plucks all the suggestion values and returns them as an array.

Comment: If this is truly parsed JSON then this should be `result.pluck('suggestion')` as JSON is always parsed to `String` keys

Comment: Thanks sachin and vasfed.. it worked for me.